# DOM traversing with jQuery - Are there performance hits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, traversal

I'm currently loading 300 + items onto the page to filter through. The current page and filtering load are terrible.

After looking through the code, I noticed I wasn't originally referencing ID's first. For example:

```
$('.item > input:checked','#container')
```

Now, this approach has been used constantly throughout my JS file.

Would the following improve the performance?

```
$('#container > .drop-content > .item > input:checked')
```

If not, what are the best ways for improving this?

Thanks all.

Comment: You can try yourself: http://jsperf.com/. The best way would probably be to *not* use jQuery selector extensions (such as `:checked`) so that jQuery can make use of native browser methods (such as `querySelectorAll`).

Comment: A lot depends on your HTML. Can you post some?

Answer (score 0):

There is a considerable difference between `$('.block a')` and `$('.block').find('a')`.

There are [a lot of jQuery methods for traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/). Using them is much better in terms of performance, than complex selectors.

Comment: Thanks Skip. When using the browser console to look up different combinations, such as 
$('.item > input:checked','#container') - Returns fast
$('#container > .drop-content > .item > input:checked') - returns fast
$('#container').find('.drop-content').find('.item').find('input:checked') - 5 seconds slower

I could be getting the above syntax completely wrong. As it's a large file to modify, i'm looking for the best approach.

Comment: Aren't there any css-classes on the input? It would be much quicker to have `$('.block').find('.input_class');`

Comment: There are. I've updated the entire document using ".find()" / ".children()" etc, unfortunately the speed hasn't increased. I will re investigate, as it's clearly something else. Thank you all for your responses.